# Inefficient functions - how to assign colour to datapoints in Highchart

Tags: javascript, function, highcharts

I am trying to create a progress bar for surveys. Depending on the progress, I would like to assign colors dynamically to each data point. I have managed this, but it seems that the functions takes ages to run. At least, that is my interpretation as I am new to much of this.

So my question is: How can I assign colors to the data points more effectively? I am not sure how to reference to the different colors within Highcharts if I create and store multiple colors in one function.

http://jsfiddle.net/oskjerv/v4Lx69Lv/

Hope my question makes sense to some/any of you.

All the best.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [''],
        visible:false,
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        visible:false
        
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true,
        enabled:false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            animation:false
        }
    },
    labels: {
       enabled: false
   },
   tooltip: { 
      enabled: false 
   },
   exporting:{
      enabled:false
   },
   credits:{
      enabled:false
   },
    series: [{
        name: 'Del1',
        data: [.20],
        color: getColourFirst()
    }, {
        name: 'Del2',
        data: [.20],
        color: getColourSecond()
    }, {
        name: 'Del3',
        data: [.20],
        color: getColourThird()
    },
    {
        name: 'Del4',
        data: [.20],
        color: getColourFourth()
    },
    {
        name: 'Del4',
        data: [.20],
        color: getColourFifth()
    }]
});

function getColourFirst(){
var colour1=['#D5D4D4'];
return colour1;
}
function getColourSecond(){
var colour2=['#D5D4D4'];
return colour2;
}
function getColourThird(){
var colour3=['#87bdd8'];
return colour3;
}
function getColourFourth(){
var colour4=['#87bdd8'];
return colour4;
}
function getColourFifth(){
var colour5=['#87bdd8'];
return colour5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are saying `color: ['#87bdd8']`. This is not a valid format. In short you are looking for `color: '#87bdd8'` instead. See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4Lx69Lv/6/) for a demo, and see [the Colors description](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) for more detail on the syntax.

When it comes to how to solve the colors there are a million ways to do it, but I'd probably suggest something that uses an index instead of all separate unautomatable function names. For example:

```
myColors = ['#D5D4D4','#D5D4D4','#87bdd8','#87bdd8','#87bdd8'];

function getColor(index) {
    return myColors[index%myColors.length];
}
```

Or see [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/v4Lx69Lv/7/).